# To have got through or having got through?

Tags: grammar

I was looking up for the meaning of " being over the worst of an illness" and saw this definition: " to have got through the most serious stage of an illness.

I don't get the " to have got through" part.Is it correct?  Can I use "having got through" instead?

Comment: It's an infinitive, used for the purpose of a formal definition. If someone _is over the worst_, they _have got through the most serious stage_.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for a difference between British and American English:

“Get is the present tense form of the verb. Got is the past tense form as well as one of the two alternatives for the past participle. The other alternative for the past participle is gotten, which is generally preferred in the United States.”

www.mit.edu › course › 21.guide
get/got/gotten - MIT

Answer (score 0):

"Having got through" is used when another event has occurred afterward. It is similar to an IF-THEN type statement

"Having got through the most serious stage of the illness, he returned to his work."

"To have got through" is correct when defining just a stand-alone event.